# Recurrence with floor function

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Solve the recurrence relation$$a_n=a_{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}}+n$$with $a_1=1$.

I am interested in the recurrence above. I tried taking two case, one with $n$ even and other with odd to avoid the floor function. But that gave me two recurrences which I am not able to solve. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try solving the recurrence for $n=2^k$ first?

Comment: @5xum Yes, it can easily be calculated

Comment: Have a look at http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+4%2C+7%2C+8%2C+10%2C+11%2C+15%2C+16%2C+18%2C+19%2C+22%2C+23%2C+25%2C+26%2C+31%2C+32%2C+34%2C+35%2C++38&sort=&language=&go=Search